# script and link tags inside if else condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I create new project In my new project `index.html` I made below code for project build. now I have two commands for run project

```
1. npm run admin-watch
2. npm run web-watch
```

Now I want to  build project if-else condition wise if extension is `admin` then allow to build if condition else else condition. but how to allow multiple script tag and link tag in inside if condition of javascript ?

index.html

```
let pathname = window.location.pathname;
let splitPath = pathname.split('/')[1];
if(splitPath === admin){
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/web/css/style.css">
  <script src="/build/web/js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/build/web/js/manifest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/build/web/js/vendor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}else{
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/admin/css/admin.css">
  <script src="/build/admin/js/admin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/build/admin/js/manifest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/build/admin/js/vendor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Comment: thats not how javascript / html works

Comment: is it for react as per tags? use ternary operator rather if else

Comment: @JoeWarner what are you said I not understand ? how to solve this problem

Comment: @AZ_ can you help me to use ternery operator

Comment: refer https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for what you need, which is calling a function at runtime that inserts the appropriate script tag based on your condition:

```
function loadMyScripts(){
    let pathname = window.location.pathname;
    let splitPath = pathname.split('/')[1];
    if(splitPath === admin){
      let link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = "stylesheet";
      link.href = "/build/web/css/style.css"
      document.head.appendChild(link);

      let scriptOne = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = "/build/web/js/index.js";
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      document.head.appendChild(scriptOne);

      // the rest of the scripts have the same approach, just change src and type attribute
    }else{
      //create more element objects with other attributes and append them to the head as above
    }
}
```